# How to edit saved data from clicked ListView item?

Tags: android, listview

I have two Activities. In `CreateAccount` class I'm making a `listView` with all account which a user had saved. In Accounts class I'm saving data, which appears in new row in the `listView` from `CreateAccount` class.

I want when a `listView` item is selected to be able to edit the saved information and when the button Save is pressed to save the new data. My problem is that when I edit saved information and click the Save button it doesn't change this account, but makes another one with the changed information. Can you help me fix this?

Here is my code

```
public class CreateAccount extends ListActivity {

Intent intent;
Button button3;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
SharedPreferences preferences;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAccount.this, Accounts.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int num = Accounts.num;
    num = preferences.getInt("Account_num", num);
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        list.add(preferences.getString("account_name_" + i, ""));
    }
    listItems.addAll(list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAccount.this, Accounts.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
}
}


public class Accounts extends Activity {
static EditText webSite;
EditText userName;
EditText pass;
Button save;
SharedPreferences preferences;
Intent intent;
static int num;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accounts);

    webSite = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
    intent = getIntent();

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Accounts.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
            int num;
            num = app_preferences.getInt("Account_num", 0);
            num++;
            editor.putInt("Account_num", num);
            String list = webSite.getText().toString();
            editor.putString("account_name_" + num, list);
            editor.putString("account_user_" + num, userName.getText()
                    .toString());

            editor.putString("account_pass_" + num, pass.getText()
                    .toString());
            editor.commit();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Accounts.this, CreateAccount.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }

    });

    num = intent.getIntExtra("position", -1);
    num++;
    if (num != -1) {

        String list = intent.getStringExtra("account_name_");
        preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Accounts.this);
        webSite.setText(preferences.getString("account_name_" + num,
                webSite.getText().toString()));
        userName.setText(preferences.getString("account_user_" + num,
                userName.getText().toString()));
        pass.setText(preferences.getString("account_pass_" + num, pass
                .getText().toString()));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that you change the key with "account_name_" + num. SharedPreferences is a key value store. You can change the values if you apply the put methods to the same keys.

Comment: What do you mean by "put methods to the same key"?

Comment: Lets assume you have stored one account under the key account_name_1. Then you want to edit and save that account. In the save onclick listener you are incrementing it to account_name_2 and saving it. So another item account_name_2 is stored in the SharedPreferences, instead of editing account_name_1 and according values.

Comment: Yes, but how can I change this? If I don't have this +num I will not know if I'm opening account_1 or account_2.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i meant the num++ operation.

Comment: If I remove num++ when I open an account it shows me the saves data from the previous account.